# How will I able to convert '"+g.getLearningfile()+"' into a varbinary(max)?

Tags: java, sql

How will I able to convert `'"+g.getLearningfile()+"'` into a `varbinary(max)` in java?

```
public int save(CourseModel g) {
    String sql = "insert into TBL_COURSE (COURSE_NAME,COURSE_DESCRIPTION,COURSE_LEARNINGFILE,COURSE_CATEGORY_ID) values ( '"+g.getCourse_name()+"','"+g.getCourse_description()+"','"+g.getLearningfile()+"','"+g.getCoursecategory_id()+"')";
    return template.update(sql);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In java? You should add the tag